# Installing Ubuntu14.01 on virtualbox Erase disk?

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, windows-8

I'm currently running windows8.1 and wish to install Ubuntu14.01 on VirtualBox.

Upon the "Installation type" screen it gives me the option to:

1) Erase disk and install Ubuntu [Warning: this will delete any files on the disk]

2) Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security

3) Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation

4) Something else.

Forgive my ignorance, but i'm relatively new to virtualization, anyway heres my question:

Does choice (1) imply erasing my current disk/files from which I run windows8.1 on? My intuition suggests not, since its a 'virtual desktop'. When I choose "something else" to potentially partition my hard drive, the only entry that appears is "/dev/sda ATA VBOX HARDDISK(8.6GB)"

So would it be safe to choose option 1, and it not affect my current disk/files from my windows OS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR - any option is safe, option 1 being the easiest.

When you created the virtual machine to install Ubuntu on, Virtualbox asked you to create a virtual drive.

Unless you explicitly exposed your physical disks to your virtual machine (it's *very* unlikely you've done this accidentally), your virtual machine is constrained to that virtual disk (ATA VBOX HARDDISK(8.6GB)) which resides in a file on the physical disk.

Therefore you can do whatever you please from within that VM and it won't be able to touch anything outside that file, i.e. it won't affect anything on your Windows partition (except for space occupied by the virtual disk backing file, that is).

Comment: You're welcome - good luck!